Does the number of resources affect compile time with the Xtend Maven plugin?
I am using the Xtend Maven plugin for a large project, and over time, I’ve noticed a gradual increase in compile time during the build process. One key observation is that the resource count in the xtend-gen directory has exceeded 10,000 files.
My questions are:

Does the number of resources (Xtend or generated Java files) significantly affect the compile time when using the Xtend Maven plugin?

Is there any known dependency between resource count and compile performance in Xtend?

What strategies can be implemented to optimize the compilation process for projects with a high resource count?

Are there specific configurations in the Xtend Maven plugin to limit or manage the impact of large resource counts?


Additional Details:

Build environment: Maven 3.1, Java 8, Xtend Maven Plugin version 2.28.0.
Observed behavior: Compile time increases by 1–2 minutes daily, likely due to growing resource count.

Try reducing the resource count by 50 classes, the build time was significantly reduced from 7 hours to 40 minutes.

Why are you using ancient old Maven Version 3.1???

This is an older project, and I have tried using the latest Maven Compiler Plugin version on my local machine as well. After profiling, I observed that the xtend-maven-plugin is consuming significantly more time during the build process. There haven't been any unusual changes in the codebase recently, but the project now includes 10,000+ Xtend files. I’m wondering if there is any threshold or inherent limitation within the xtend-maven-plugin that could be contributing to this bottleneck.
